# Building two separate builds using same code base with --prod --aot

Tags: angular, build

[image]I've created two projects in angular.json using the same code base. ng serve and ng build are working fine for both projects. But when I build it using --aot --prod, it builds every modules.

JFI
Modules are loaded based on routing, i.e., if there are 7 modules, for one project only 2 modules are needed and for another, 5 modules are needed.

I've only created 2 different app modules for both projects.

So is there any way for generating two different builds with their respective modules only?

Comment: What are JFI modules ?

Comment: Sorry. its a mistake. its not a module. "JFI" for Just for info.

Comment: Oh like FYI :D Got it. But to be honest, that's the only thing I got from your question ... Could you explain more thoroughly your issue ?

Comment: I've created 2 projects inside angular.json. I've not create seperate workspace for both projects. Instead of it, i've created 2 app modules and based on requirement, declared modules for this projects. ng build and ng serve both are serving me required modules, but in case of --prod build, all modules were builded

Comment: Then builde only the one you want with `--configuration` ? Use a script in your `package.json` like `build:firstProject` ?

Comment: Tried 
node --max-old-space-size=5120 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --project='PROJECT NAME' --configuration=production

it is still building whole project

Comment: Well if you add the flag yes (I also think it's AOT by default)

Comment: Wait, do you mean you have two projects as in twice the source code ? They're not projects in `angular.json` file ?

Comment: Added a screenshot. Please refer it.